# Ограничение ввода в поле input

Tags: html

есть `input` в котором должно быть не больше двух цифр и числа должны быть только от 10 до 30, и запрет ввода букв. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Использовать какую-нибудь Js-маску. Например:  https://unmanner.github.io/imaskjs/

Comment: `input number` как раз для этого

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров "Джаваскрипта двести метров грузят текста триста байт..." О чем это я? Используйте `input type="number"`, и не надо нагружать клиента.

Comment: @Anamnian , я же только за. Но не во всех современных браузерах в `input type="number"` стоит запрет на ввод букв. Будет ли последующая валидация - неизвестно.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров Согласно [ссылке](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) только опера мини не поддерживает, для iOS Safari*, Chrome for Android, UC Browser for Android, Samsung Internet отключена возможность юзать стрелочки, что не критично для автора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using number inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

```
<input type="number" min="10" max="30" />
```

Если поле обязательное к заполнению можно добавить `required`

```
<input type="number" min="10" max="30" required />
```